# Convergence of $g_n(x)=x^\frac{1}{n} $ in $(C[0,1],|| \cdot ||_\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

In a Functional Analisys assignment I was asked to check for convergence of the following sequence
$$
 n\in\mathbb{N}: g_n(x) = x^\frac{1}{n}
$$
in $C[0,1]$ with respect to the following norm:
$$
||f||_\infty = \max{|f(x)|}
$$
I am convinced that this does not converge and argued that is not a cauchy sequence.
The grader just noted that the series is in fact convergent but did not note much more.

After having looked at my proof some times I am still unclear were the argument fails and would be greatful if somebody could help me figure this out.

**My Proof**

One can see that $\forall n$,since $x \in [0,1]$, we have that
$$
\min(g_n(x)) = 0, \max(g_n(x)) = 1
$$
and $g_n(x)$ is continuos and monotonly growing.

Therefore, $\forall \epsilon \in (0,1)\exists x_0\in [0,1]$ so that
$$
x_0^\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon <1 
$$
Now we can see that
$$
  x_0^\frac{1}{m}-x_0^\frac{1}{n}>\epsilon \iff 
$$
$$
-\frac{1}{m}|ln(x_0)|>-|ln(\epsilon + x_0^\frac{1}{n})|\iff
$$
$$
m>\frac{|ln(x_0)|}{|ln(\epsilon +x_0^\frac{1}{n})|}
$$
one can pick $m>n$ that fullfills this inequality.
Then we can se that
$$
||g_n(x)-g_m(x)||_\infty \geq x_0^\frac{1}{m} - x_0^\frac{1}{n}>\epsilon
$$

And $g_n(x)$ is therefore not a cauchy sequence with respect to $||\cdot||_\infty$.

Comment: If $(g_n)$ converges w.r.t to the supremum norm, then it also converges pointwise. Doesn't $(g_n)$ converge pointwise to $g$ with $g(0) = 0$ and $g(x)=1$ for $x>0$?

Comment: A function defined like the one that you propose is not continuos, the exercise asked for convergence in C[0,1] so therefore...yes it converges pointwiese to that, but that is outside of the vectorspace, so that would suggest that "I am right", no?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my point. If $(g_n)$ were convergent/Cauchy w.r.t to the supremum norm, then it converges uniformly, hence also pointwise, to a continuous function. But it converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, so $(g_n)$ cannot be convergent/Cauchy.

Comment: Now the question is, we are not supposed to know about the equivalence between this norm and pointwise convergence, without using this is my proof sufficient to show that?

Comment: Convergence in the supremum norm is equivalent to uniform convergence. They imply pointwise convergence, but not the other way around. I am surprised you are not supposed to know this, since this is used to show completeness of $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$g_{2n}(x)-g_{n}(x)=x^{1/(2n)}-x^{1/n}=x^{1/(2n)}(1-x^{1/(2n)})$$ For $x_n=2^{-2n}$ we get $$g_{2n}(x_n)-g_{n}(x_n)={1\over 4}$$ which implies $\|g_{2n}-g_n\|_\infty \ge {1\over 4}.$ Hence the sequence $g_n$ does not satisfy the Cauchy condition.